# Can I use the query input parameter to have different where condiction? (something like an IF statment)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I have the following problem woring on a **MySql** query. I try to explain you what I have to do.

I have this query, it works fine:

```
SELECT
    LNG.id                                          AS language_id,
    LNG.language_name                               AS language_name,
    LNG.language_code                               AS language_code,
    CLP.is_default                                  AS id_default_language

FROM Country_Language_Preference                    AS CLP
INNER JOIN Country                                 AS CNT
      ON CLP.country_id = CNT.id
INNER JOIN Languages                               AS LNG
      ON CLP.language_id = LNG.id
WHERE
      CNT.country_name = "Senegal"
```

This query have a single **WHERE** input parameter, this:

```
CNT.country_name = "Senegal"
```

I want to implement the following behavior: if the passed parameter have value **Senegal** or **Rwanda** perform the previous query.

If this input parameter have a different value form **Senegal** or **Rwanda**  perform the same query but using this **WHERE** condition_

```
CNT.country_name = "GLOBAL"
```

Can I do something like this using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CASE` Statement, this should be possible.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    LNG.id                                          AS language_id,
    LNG.language_name                               AS language_name,
    LNG.language_code                               AS language_code,
    CLP.is_default                                  AS id_default_language

FROM Country_Language_Preference                    AS CLP
INNER JOIN Country                                 AS CNT
      ON CLP.country_id = CNT.id
INNER JOIN Languages                               AS LNG
      ON CLP.language_id = LNG.id
WHERE
      CNT.country_name = CASE WHEN @Country = "Senegal" OR @Country = "Rwanda" THEN "Senegal"
                         ELSE "GLOBAL" END
```

Comment: mmm, maybe I am loosing something...but in this example I can I specify what is my passed input param?

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions in `WHERE` clauses, instead of `case` _expressions_.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `OR`:

```
WHERE (CNT.country_name = @country OR @country = 'GLOBAL')
```

`@country` is whatever parameter you are passing in.

If you want to limit to those two countries, then:

```
WHERE (CNT.country_name = @country OR
       (@country NOT IN ('Rwanda', 'Senegal') AND CNT.country_name = 'GLOBAL')
      )
```

But the first version seems more versatile.

Comment: I want the second one but for example using "Italy" in this way I obtain an empty result set:
WHERE (CNT.country_name = "Senegal" OR
(@country NOT IN ('Rwanda', 'Senegal') AND CNT.country_name = 'GLOBAL')
)